Azure DevOps: Current column in query
I was wondering how to get the current COLUMN of a task in a query when using DevOps sprints. All I can export is Board Column, Board Column Done, which both return nothing. Area Path also doesn't solve the question.
I've noticed when you drag across columns it's also not reflected in the history of the item.


I am afraid that there is no such task work item field can show the current Column of the Sprint taskboard in query.
Currently, Azure DevOps only supports displaying column information in Azure Boards -> Boards(e.g. Issue, User Story, Feaute, Epic) through Board Column field. Refer to this doc:  Query changes to a Kanban board
There is no built-in or custom field that can automatically display information about the task column in the Sprint taskboard for the time being.
I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: Developer Community to report this feature
